# Display jquery datepicker value in php

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I have a form with a datepicker and I want to pass the selected date to my php file but it doesn't seem to work.

My html is like this

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.domainname.com/?from=20/04/2014&to=25/04/2014" name="easy_widget_form" id="easy_widget_form">
<div class="input_container">
    <div class="input_prefix">
        Check in:
    </div><input id="easy-widget-datepicker-from" type="text" name="from" value="20.04.2014" class="hasDatepicker">
</div>
<div class="input_container">
    <div class="input_prefix">
        Check out:
    </div><input id="easy-widget-datepicker-to" type="text" name="to" value="25.04.2014" class="hasDatepicker">
</div>
    <p class="easy-submit"><input type="submit" class="easybutton" value="Reserve now!"> </p>
</form>
```

Javascript :

```
jQuery('#easy-form-from,#easy-widget-datepicker-from').val(d);
```

But when I echo $easy-widget-datepicker-from in my php file, it doesn't show anything. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do is not clear,can you please explain it properly.

Comment: I need to display selected datepicker in php form. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

make your page as this

**contact.php**

```
<?PHP
if($_REQUEST['Submit']=='Reserve now!'){
        echo $from= $_POST['from'];
        echo $to= $_POST['to'];
}
?>
<form method="post" action="contact.php" name="easy_widget_form" id="easy_widget_form">
<div class="input_container">
    <div class="input_prefix">
        Check in:
    </div><input id="easy-widget-datepicker-from" type="text" name="from" value="20.04.2014" class="hasDatepicker">
</div>
<div class="input_container">
    <div class="input_prefix">
        Check out:
    </div><input id="easy-widget-datepicker-to" type="text" name="to" value="25.04.2014" class="hasDatepicker">
</div>
    <p class="easy-submit"><input name="Submit" type="submit" class="easybutton" value="Reserve now!"> </p>
</form>
```

i have made changes to your form, and submit button. Please try the above code.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Please give me some other idea.

Comment: could you show me how you get the post values? is it using isset  or $_POST['Submit']="Reserve now!" ?

Comment: I tried to display it as if(isset($_POST['from'])) { echo $_POST['from']; }

Comment: Please see the updated answer. I have done the whole page itself. try saving it as contact.php and run it. if you get the answer, it means its because you pointed the form action wrongly

Comment: I tried, but no result. I'm using http://wordpress.org/plugins/easyreservations/ this plugin. I need to pass datepicker in php form.

Comment: I am just lost, how are you able to use Wordpress Plugin in classic php ? are you working with Wordpress ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50938/discussion-between-raghu-and-akhil-sidharth)

Answer (score 0):

php only takes "name" not "id"

so echo "$_POST['from']" to get "easy-widget-datepicker-from"'s value

Comment: The format goes like this 
<input type="text" name="somename" value="somevalue"/>
on submit php gets the value like this
$_REQUEST['somename'](_REQUEST so it can get both GET and POST value) it should give you "somevalue"